# how to pass data from appdelegate to index.html in jquerymobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is appdelegate.m   to get device token  same thing how to write in phonegap in index.js

Appdelegate.m

```
(BOOL) application: (UIApplication * ) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary * ) launchOptions {
    CGRect screenBounds = [
        [UIScreen mainScreen] bounds
    ];
    [
        [UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)
    ];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0; - (void) application: (UIApplication * ) application didReceiveRemoteNotification: (NSDictionary * ) userInfo {} - (void) application: (UIApplication * ) application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: (NSData * ) deviceToken {
        NSString * devtoken = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", deviceToken];
        NSLog(@"the devicetoken is %@", devtoken);
        NSRange r1 = [devtoken rangeOfString: @"<"];
        NSRange r2 = [devtoken rangeOfString: @">"];
        NSRange rSub = NSMakeRange(r1.location + r1.length, r2.location - r1.location - r1.length);
        NSString * sub = [devtoken substringWithRange: rSub];
        NSLog(@"%@", sub);
        NSString * newString = [sub stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" "
            withString: @""
        ];
        UIAlertView * message = [
            [UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Device Token!"
            message: newString
            delegate: nil
            cancelButtonTitle: @"OK"
            otherButtonTitles: nil
        ];
        [message show];
        NSLog(@"%@", newString);
    } - (void) application: (UIApplication * ) application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: (NSError * ) error {
        NSLog(@"the reason for fail to register the remote notifications is %@", error);
    }
```

Comment: have u checked push notification plugin on github.

Comment: ya i checked  it is coming in appdelegate.m   finally device token is coming but it must store in html variable i.e index.html

Comment: Please follow my answer below with PluginResult you can pass deviceToken to html using "self writeJavascript" in that code.

Answer (score 0):

you can get device token in js file like

```
- (void)didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    DLog(@"didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:%@", deviceToken);

    NSString *token = [[[[deviceToken description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]
                    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
                   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

    NSMutableDictionary *results = [PushNotification getRemoteNotificationStatus];
    [results setValue:token forKey:@"deviceToken"];

    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsDictionary:results];
    [self writeJavascript:[pluginResult toSuccessCallbackString:[self.callbackIds valueForKey:@"registerDevice"]]];
}
```

in above code pluginResult will be passed and like wise we can get deviceToken in callback function.

please find push notification plugin from below links

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-push-notification

Comment: In appdelegate itself. The above method is also available in your given code. plz check it.

Comment: have u implemented push notification plugin for phonegap ?

Comment: check my answer again

Comment: ya i am getting device token also but i have to send this token to server url which was written in index.html

Comment: do you know about CDVPluginResult ?

Comment: have u implemented push notification plugin and import it into AppDelegate.m file and what is error coming?

Comment: `NSString *jsStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.plugins.pushNotification.notificationCallback(%@);", DeviceToken];
 [self writeJavascript:jsStatement];` Try with this